# How to groupby a column and find the sum of multiple columns in pandas

Tags: pandas, numpy

I want to group by column 'A' and find the sum of all the remaining values on the columns.How to perform using groupby?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = {'A' : [1,2,3,4,5],
        'B' : [6,7,8,9,10],
        'C' : [11,12,13,14,15]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['A','B','C'],index = [0,1,2,3,4])
print(df)
print('*'*40)
df1 = pd.concat(
    [
        df,
        pd.DataFrame(
            [[np.random.randint(10000), np.random.randint(10000), np.random.randint(10000),np.random.randint(10000),np.random.randint(10000),np.random.randint(10000),np.random.randint(10000),np.random.randint(10000),np.random.randint(10000),np.random.randint(10000),np.random.randint(10000),np.random.randint(10000),np.random.randint(10000),np.random.randint(10000),np.random.randint(10000)]], 
            index=df.index, 
            columns=['X', 'Y', 'Z','D','E','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P']
        )
    ], axis=1
)

print(df1)
```

I want to store the sum of the columns to a new dataframe.

```
Columns output:
       A   B   C     X     Y     Z     D     E     G     H    I     J     K     L  \
    0  1   6  11  1093  7323  7671  1818  6320  1802  3780  559  9017  6184  4191   
    1  2   7  12  1093  7323  7671  1818  6320  1802  3780  559  9017  6184  4191   
    2  3   8  13  1093  7323  7671  1818  6320  1802  3780  559  9017  6184  4191   
    3  4   9  14  1093  7323  7671  1818  6320  1802  3780  559  9017  6184  4191   
    4  5  10  15  1093  7323  7671  1818  6320  1802  3780  559  9017  6184  4191   

         M     N     O     P  
    0  306  3496  8181  1709  
    1  306  3496  8181  1709  
    2  306  3496  8181  1709  
    3  306  3496  8181  1709  
    4  306  3496  8181  1709
```

example:I try to find the sum of all the rows groupby A and store the sum in a new dataframe!

```
df1.shape
(5, 18)


df1.iloc[:,1:18].groupby(by = ['A'],axis = 1).sum()
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit further? Each value in `A` is unique, so a groupby function won't do anything. Can you show an example of what output you are looking for? Also what exactly is df and df1?

Comment: what you seem to want is `new_df = df1.groupby('A').sum().reset_index()`?

Comment: @Ben T . This is what i was looking for.Thanks for understanding :)